# Every isomorphism on a separable Banach space has a completely invariant dense subset

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

If $T$ is an isomorphism acting on a separable Banach space, can we always find a countable dense subset $D$ of $X$ such that $T(D)=D? $

Comment: Take any countable dense subset $E$ and let $D=\bigcup T^n E$.

Comment: Heh, you changed the question but my answer still applies because I strategically left out the range of index $n$.

Comment: @Fundamental You are right, it was trivial. Modified it to what actually I am trying to prove. Still trivial?

Comment: Yep, still trivial: just include negative $n$.

Comment: I can see that $T(D)\subset D$. But why equality? If you exclude $n=0$ (so no $E$ in $D$), why is still dense? Probably I am missing something easy :)

Comment: Take union over all $n\in\mathbb Z$, including $0$ of course. The idea is that the union consists of two-sided *orbits* under the group $(T^n)$. Each such orbit is completely invariant by definition.

Comment: Of course, I see now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary of comments: yes, such $D$ can be obtained as 
$$D=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}T^n E$$
where $E$ is any countable dense subset of $X$.

Comment: Thank you. Can you pick $D$ such that is linearly independent? Don't tell me is still trivial :)

Comment: Not in a finite-dimensional space; I don't know about infinite-dimensional case. Please ask a new question, referring to this one if it helps to add context.