# Isomorphisms with invariant linearly independent dense subset.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

If $T$ is an isomorphism acting on a separable Banach space $X$, can we find a countable, dense, linearly independent set $D\subset X$ such that $T(D)=D$? If $X$ is finite dimensional, then the answer is no, since $D$ would need to be finite, thus not dense. So the question is relevant only when $X$ is infinite dimensional.

The question is a follow-up question to the one below.

[Every isomorphism on a separable Banach space has a completely invariant dense subset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128565/every-isomorphism-on-a-separable-banach-space-has-a-completely-invariant-dense-s?noredirect=1#comment2303444_1128565)